# Spring Security - ACL readAclsById not filtering by SIDs

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I'm trying to use Spring Security's readAclsById method in `JdbcMutableAclService` to retrieve ACLs that are filtered by the SIDs. However, ACLs that are not applicable to the passed-in SIDs are returned.

I'm creating the ACL entry using the username:

```
public void add(Object domainObject, String username, List<Permission> permissions) {
    MutableAcl acl;

    ObjectIdentity oid = objectIdentityRetrievalStrategy
            .getObjectIdentity(domainObject);
    Sid receipient = new PrincipalSid(username);
    try {
        acl = (MutableAcl) aclService.readAclById(oid);
    } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
        acl = aclService.createAcl(oid);
    }
    for(Permission permission:permissions) {
        acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), permission, receipient, true);
    }
    aclService.updateAcl(acl);
}
```

And I'm retrieving ACLs via the `Authentication` object:

```
        List<Sid> sids = sidRetrievalStrategy.getSids(authentication);

        List<ObjectIdentity> identities = new ArrayList<>(domainObjects.size());
        for (Object domainObject : domainObjects) {
            identities.add(objectIdentityRetrievalStrategy.getObjectIdentity(domainObject));
        }

        Map<ObjectIdentity, Acl> acls = aclService.readAclsById(identities, sids);

        //see what permissions the user has for these objects
        for (Map.Entry<ObjectIdentity, Acl> entry : acls.entrySet()) {
            Acl acl = entry.getValue();
            //entries that are not applicable to the SIDs are returned    
            List<AccessControlEntry> entries = acl.getEntries();
        }
```

If I log into another username and try to retrieve the ACLs via readAclsById, I also get `AccessControlEntry` values that belonged to the other usernames. Am I using `AclService` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after some digging around the source code: the default implementation uses `BasicLookupStrategy` which ignores the SIDs by default.